# How to convert a time line graph to integral graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, integral

I want to go from the timeline chart that display data over time to integral chart with D3.js.

I have this array of data and I want the integral chart.

```
 const array1 = [
    {ts: 1632661247, value: 10},
    {ts: 1632661248, value: 12},
    {ts: 1632667255, value: 8},
    {ts: 1632667315, value: 7}
    //...
    {ts: 1632667320, value: -3},
    {ts: 1632667330, value: -10},
    {ts: 1632667332, value: 14},
    ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please  post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.